# How to setup docker-machine to be as default?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I want to rebuild everything from my docker VM named `default`, I used `docker-compose down` but it only removed the containers, all the requirements are still installed and I would like it to be as it was from the beginning so I can 're'-setup everything. Is it possible ?

Comment: have you tried `docker-compose build`? `down` only remove containers, If the images are already builded, they don´t get builded again automatically by compose

Comment: @Robert Yes the problem isn't about rebuilding the containers, the first time I `build` everything works, but when I put it `down` and re`build` it again some codes doesn't work anymore, why is that ?

Comment: We will need more details to know the problem

Comment: @Robert The first time you build in docker-compose it'll configure and install loads of packages. When you put docker-compose down and rebuild again it'll take less time since the packages are already installed. I would like to do a full reset and set it as it was new. The only way I've found is to erase the VM default and restart the quickstart terminal so it'll create it again. Is there a way to do so through the terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove all containers, images and volumes

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker image rm $(docker image ls -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

There are other things like networks and secrets that will not be removed, but they should not cause any problems.

If you are using a newer version of docker try the `docker system prune -a` command instead.

But maybe the `--no-cache` argumant ist the real solution for your problem. With it, docker will not use the cache and will do a full rebuild of the image.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution that will ignore previous builds:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

But if you want something more destructive:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create default
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Comment: `docker-compose build --no-cache` will be useful ! I know it's of topic but could you explain me what `docker-compose up -d` does comparing to `docker-compose up` ?

Comment: Yes. The difference is that `-d` will *detach* you from the containers output so you can continue using your terminal. To attach do this: `docker compose logs -f`

Comment: this made it very clear ! So I don't need to use docker-compose up right after docker-compose up -d